# XY coordinates within vb application only

Tags: vb.net

I am learning visual studio and just creating random apps. I was wondering if there is a way to get the x and y coordinates of the mouse only inside the vb app window and not outside of it? I tried something like this `TextBox1.Text = MousePosition.X : TextBox2.Text = MousePosition.Y` but that gives me x and y of the entire screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach [MouseMove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) event handler in your form.

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove
   Label1.Text = "X." & e.X & vbCrLf & "Y." & e.Y
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks works does this work on the webbrowser? i am trying to make a form filler. That is flash based.